# How do you say lychee? Does it have a kanji as well?

Tags: kanji

I can’t seem to find any information on it other than “ライチ” but I only found that from one website.:/

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B7

Answer (score 2):

If you mean this fruit:

[image: ハーゲンダッツ ライチ&ラズベリー]

Then yes, it's normally called ライチ. It's popular in cocktails served at izakaya. It has kanji (茘枝), but this is not recognized by average Japanese speakers. Most people recognize this as ライチ, but according to Wikipedia, レイシ seems to be a more authentic name in botanical contexts.

Comment: OMG that looks so good